# Licensing issue in ZFS when building kernel with CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, zfs

When I build the mainline Ubuntu kernel (hirsute) with CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC on, the build process fails giving the below error message

`configure: error: Kernel built with CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC which is incompatible with the CDDL license and will prevent the module linking stage from succeeding. You must rebuild your kernel without this option enabled.`

Turns out ZFS builds with a CDDL license which is causing a problem. I don't require ZFS support, so is there a way wherein I can build my kernel without ZFS? Alternatively, DKMS fetches the ZFS deb file from the internet, so can I build ZFS locally (where I would change the license in the META file to GPL) and make the kernel use that instead of fetching the package from the internet.

I follow the steps given [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) to build my kernel.

Comment: Do not change licence in META if you didn't talk with a lawyer (especially if you are dealing with license of certain companies): you are financially responsible of it. Ubuntu provide you kernel sources and receipt to build kernel (as shipped with Ubuntu), just remove ZFS after you get in place sources (with Ubuntu patches) and you start building the sources).

Comment: I am a little new to kernel land. Could you please guide me on how to remove ZFS from my build process. I have updated the question to reflect the source from where I follow the steps to build my kernel.

Comment: Can't you just uninstall the `zfs-dkms` package if you do not need it?

Answer (score 2):

The fix turned out to be pretty simple. I could turn off zfs support while building the kernel by flipping the `do_zfs` flag to false in the amd64.mk (There is one for each arch, so choose accordingly) file in kernel source.